# Why use the cosine distance for machine translation (Mikolov paper)?

Tags: word2vec, word-embeddings, cosine-similarity, machine-translation

I am currently reading the paper "Exploiting Similarities among Languages for Machine Translation" by Mikolov et al. (available here : https://static.googleusercontent.com/media/research.google.com/en//pubs/archive/44931.pdf) and I was wondering why they used the cosine similarity to find the closest word to z (page 4, after equation (3)) instead of a more classic distance (like the squared sum of differences of each component).

So my question is large : why this distance since when computing the matrix W, it should act as a rotation and a scaling ? And is there any record of using word embeddings with different distance metrics and their results ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's still very much an open question of which distance metrics to use for word2vec when defining "similar" words. Cosine similarity is quite nice because it implicitly assumes our word vectors are normalized so that they all sit on the unit ball, in which case it's a natural distance (the angle) between any two. As well, words that are similar *tend* to have vectors be close to each-other, especially in length, which means that their magnitudes are comparable, and so again cosine distance becomes natural.

In reality this is much more complex, because word2vec does not explicitely require that the embedding vectors all have length 1. Indeed there is work that shows that there is important information hidden in the lengths of vectors, so that L2 distance can be used. See here for example:

https://arxiv.org/pdf/1508.02297v1.pdf

Comment: Any updates after 5 years or more ? :) Do we know more?

Comment: Also, could it be linked to the fact that in high-dimensional spaces, Euclidean distance becomes less meaningful ? If distance from a given point concentrates around a sphere of radius sqrt(d/3) around that point as explicited [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curse_of_dimensionality#Distance_function), maybe a notion of angle has better explicative power? (I know very little about the subject, just speculating)

Answer (score 0):

A hypothesis on why the `cosine similarity` loss could be more efficient for training neural networks on parallel sentences comprised of Word2Vec vectors:

The `mean squared error` loss optimizes the different dimensions of the output w2v vector independently. It treats the vector as an array of independent numbers, which is actually not the case since they all contribute to/are a function of the higher-order geometric/semantic properties of the word vector.

The `cosine similarity` loss on the other hand, takes into account the geometric relationships that exist between the different components of the Word2Vec vector. And so gradient updates should systematically modify these vector components in a non-greedy manner.

At any given time step, the most effective gradient update might not be one that modifies every vector component equally (as the `mse` is likely to do), but one that modifies them in a way that moves the overall output vector closer to the target.

This perspective makes sense to me- it'll be interesting to see what experiments have to say.